# Why I can't see borders for columns in this table row?

Tags: html, css, html-table

What I have is an html page and here an image for it :

[image]

As you can see I have a table and in the first row the border works just fine but in the next one in the table it doesn't show the vertical lines instead it shows around each button which I don't want too .. and the horizontal one its cut between each cell .. and I guess it's because of the margin .. so how can I make the horizontal lines continuous and the vertical lines appear? Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
<table>
<tr>
<td width="188px" class="button" ><img src="b2.png" /></td>

<td width="188px" class="button" ></td>
<td width="188px" class="button" ></td>
<td width="188px" class="button" ></td>
<td width="188px" class="button" ><img src="b1.png" /></td>
<td width="188px" class="button" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and here is CSS :

```
.button {
    width:180px;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgb(51,153,51);
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:1px;
      margin-bottom:1px;
        margin-left:1px;
        margin-right:12px;
    float: left; /* add this */
}

table td {

    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
     border:1.0px solid #000;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You're showing a lot of code, including a lot of code irrelevant to the question, that [does not clearly demonstrate the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/EH2Cr/) (plus: it helps to pay attention to formatting if you're expecting strangers/volunteers to help). Also, you haven't told us what you've researched/tried/debugged so far, why your attempted solutions didn't work, etc.

Comment: i show codes which are related to the issue only and this is what i have tried and i think the problem happens because of the margin ... am i clear or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of problems in your code. The first one is that you are applying `float: left` to `.button`, which matches all your `td`s. Remove that line, it completely breaks the table.

Then you can add `border-collapse: collapse` to your table.

Also I'm not sure if you intended the table to be in the `div.wrapper` or not.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bDHW6/

Comment: so what if i want to make the border around the columns only not around the rows?

Comment: @user3675605 use `border-left: solid 1x black; border-right: solid 1px black` instead of `border: solid 1px black`. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bDHW6/5/

Comment: ok in the fiddle it works just right but in my code the border start in the beginning of the button and stop ion the end of it .. the line does not continue because i but spaces between rows .. i mean between buttons , how can i keep the space? but make the border for the whole columns??

Comment: i guess it's because of the margin top and bottom for each button

Comment: @user3675605, not sure what you mean, if I add a second row you actually get the lines with no interruption: http://jsfiddle.net/bDHW6/12/

Comment: this is correct .. the border is just fine but i want to add space under the buttons to separate each row with out spearing the border .. got it?

Comment: @user3675605, to do that you will need to have the element with the `button` class to be **inside** the `td`, rather than the td itself. http://jsfiddle.net/bDHW6/14/

Comment: what do you mean by this?

Comment: @user3675605, instead of `<td class="button">...`, you need `<td><div class="button">...` Then you can either have a margin-top/bottom on the `.button` or padding-top/bottom on the `td`. There are a few other changes you'll have to make to your CSS to make it look as intended. See the jsfiddle for details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for, but I'd assume that you'd want your table style to include `border-collapse: collapse`. This will remove the spacing between adjacent cells and essentially merge their borders. As an alternative, if you still want both borders to be drawn, you might want to try `border-spacing: (distance)`.